# Send lambda logs to specific log group

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have 4 lambda function logs saved in log group /aws/lambda/function_name, I am trying to send all the logs to one centralized log group but can't find a way to do so. Is there a way to write another lambda function that takes the logs and puts it in one log group or another solution?

Comment: What is the actual problem? Why do you need them centralised? Is this for CloudWatch dashboards?

Comment: we are transporting the logs to datadog, so we want it all the logs in one log group

Comment: DataDog can subscribe to multiple log groups, and I believe the charge by volume of log messages, not number of subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [subscription](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html) to send logs from each CloudWatch logs group to OpenSearch, Kinesis or Lambda.

To send them to a single CloudWatch logs group, you would need to write a lambda.

Comment: I want to send all the logs, I am using cloudformation so what should I provide in the filterpattern. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-subscriptionfilter.html

Comment: There's a link right there that explains the filter patterns: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html